# Filter a column based on a word and perform calculation on another two columns

Tags: r, string, loops, dplyr

*Please excuse if this looks like a duplicate question. I did a long search but couldn't zero in on one.*

I have a data-set with a column for text and another with first word of the text.

There are another two columns for how many people the text was sent & how many read it.

Sample Data:

```
df <- data.frame(Word = c("Happy", "Good", "Have", "Do"), 
                 Text = c("Happy Birthday", "Good Morning", "Have a good day", 
                           "Do you have happy news"), 
                  Sent = c(10, 20, 15, 20), 
                  Read = c(8, 12, 9, 13), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I want to calculate the read rate against each word. It is calculated from texts which contain that word

I tried the below code but seems to run for ever though without any error message.

I know for loop is not efficient for 18K records in my case and a prefer an efficient solution, in R.

Appreciate any help in this regard.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(messages)){

  word <- messages$Word[i]
  messages$Rate[i] <- messages%>% filter(str_detect(string = Text, pattern = word)) %>% summarise(sum(Read)/sum(Sent))

}
```

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a reproducible example by pasting the output of `dput(messages)` or a subset of your data.

Comment: Code to create sample data added. Copied from Ronak's answer below. Thanks to him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using base R `sapply`, for every `Word` we find out the indices (`inds`) where that `Word` occurs in the dataframe. We subset and `sum` `Read` and `Sent` columns using those indices and calculate the ratio.

```
df$Rate <- with(df, sapply(Word, function(x) {
          inds = grep(paste0("\\b", x, "\\b"), Text, ignore.case = TRUE)
          sum(Read[inds])/sum(Sent[inds])
}))


df
#   Word                   Text Sent Read      Rate
#1 Happy         Happy Birthday   10    8 0.7000000
#2  Good           Good Morning   20   12 0.6000000
#3  Have        Have a good day   15    9 0.6285714
#4    Do Do you have happy news   20   13 0.6500000
```

---

If you prefer a `tidyverse` approach doing the same using `map_dbl`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
   mutate(Ratio = map_dbl(Word, function(x) {
                   inds = str_detect(Text, fixed(x, ignore_case=TRUE))
                    sum(Read[inds])/sum(Sent[inds])
}))
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(Word = c("Happy", "Good", "Have", "Do"), 
                 Text = c("Happy Birthday", "Good Morning", "Have a good day", 
                           "Do you have happy news"), 
                  Sent = c(10, 20, 15, 20), 
                  Read = c(8, 12, 9, 13), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: .. You are a star, can't thank enough. It worked like a charm. I had been struggling for hours fighting this issue. Thanks again.